# Referencing .NET assembly in IronPython project

Tags: c#, python, .net, ironpython

I have a question about adding reference to .NET assembly in IronPython project. I have a class library project in standalone C# solution. I was wondering would I be able to reference this resulting .NET assembly when I change 'Output type' of my class library project to 'Console Application'. And I found out that yes. When I compiled my class library project, I got TestLibrary.exe file and referenced it successfully in IronPython project. So, my question is: from 'pythonic' point of view there is no difference how I add .NET assembly to IronPython project: *.dll or *.exe? Would all types from .NET assembly be accessible in both cases? These both lines of code worked fine for me:

```
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath('C:\TestLibrary\TestLibrary.exe')
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath('C:\TestLibrary\TestLibrary.dll')
```

Comment: its hard to tell the difference without a test case, but i worked on a [GUI tool](https://github.com/PMoureu/iph) to flesh out any DLL from the ironpython point of view, so you can compare both outputs to check if all classes are OK. In your case the best way may be to change the file _launcher.py_ by adding `ìmport clr`, `clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath('C:\TestLibrary\TestLibrary.dll')`,  `import TestLibrary`, and then `iph.go(TestLibrary)`. I can write a proper answer if you're interested...